# Data perturbation with normal variables

Tags: r, simulation, computational-statistics

I am doing some projects related to statistics simulation using R based on "Introduction to Scientific Programming and Simulation Using R". In the Students projects session (chapter 24), I am doing the "The pipe spiders of Brunswick" problem. I am stuck on one part of an evolutionary algorithm, the part where you need to perform some data perturbation according to the follow sentence:

> With probability $0.5$ each element of the vector is perturbed,
>   independently of the others, by an amount normally distributed with
>   mean $0$ and standard deviation $0.1$.

What does being "perturbed" really mean here? I don't know which operation I should be doing with my vector to make this perturbation happen, and I'm not finding any answers to this problem. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Suppose you already have a vector $Y$ with $n$ elements. Generate another random vector $X=X_1X_2$, where $X_1 \sim$ Bernoulli(0.5) and $X_2 \sim N(0,0.1)$. then perturbed vector is $X+Y$.

Answer (score 1):

Perturbation is a method to perturb the search in a way that will allow the learning to overcome local obstacles and make progress toward the global maxima. We can do perturbation by either changing the network(for instance, random restart) or changing training data(data perturbation methods). In your case, you just randomly choose half of the items in the vector and add(or multiply or something else, thanks to @Wayne's comment) a normal distribution: $\mathcal{N}(0, 0.1)$ for them to perturb the vector.

Comment: +1 I think the key here is explaining that the perturbation is additive. It could be multiplicative, etc.

Comment: @Wayne Thank you. I explained the perturbation because I cannot find some good explanations on the Internet.

Comment: @Wayne I think it is just like the [dithering](https://blog.landr.com/what-is-dither-when-to-use/) people often do in audio signal processing.